# name 'article_read' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm using `pandas` and `numpy` as library for python. After I type the code below, it says name `'article_read'` is not defined. What's the problem here? Thanks!

```
pd.read_csv('/Volumes/Users/laura/Desktop/test.csv')

article_read[['bldNum']]
```

Comment: Have you defined it? If not, why are you surprised?

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question here.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I thought it was a function in the library. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you haven't posted your whole code i imagine that you want to store the data from test.csv inside article_read variable for doing that

use this

```
article_read = pd.read_csv('/Volumes/Users/laura/Desktop/test.csv')
article_read[['bldNum']]
```